# What should we do about these two old, popular recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, list-question

We currently have two questions that seem very similar to each other:

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/internet-communities-where-i-can-read-rate-review-short-fiction-and-post-my-own

[What are good places to post your work where it will be read by others?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/904/what-are-good-places-to-post-your-work-where-it-will-be-read-by-others)

Between them they have 49 up-votes, 15 favorites, and 22 answers.  Clearly these are important to the community.

Two questions:

1. Should they be merged?  They cover the same territory and right now you have to go to both to get a complete picture.  One of them is Community Wiki so merging it into the other would not have any reputation impact.
2. List/survey questions like this, while in-scope at the time these questions were asked, are discouraged on Stack Exchange now.  Should we lock them (or the merged question, if we merge) for historical interest?  The effect of this is to (a) add a notice saying "this is for historical interest; don't use it as a model of how to ask today" and (b) prevent changes to the post, including voting.

Comment: While I think that asking about legacy list questions in general would be a bit much, what we do with these two questions will definitely inform how we handle others.

Comment: Merge, lock, delete (not necessarily in that order).

Answer (score 4):

IMHO the two questions should be merged; their answers are quite similar and can easily be combined.

I think a historical lock would also be appropriate. Generally speaking, even back during the Red Ink Initiative, we didn't go back and dredge up old questions for revision or locking, but  if one actively comes up (or, really, gets any kind of attention) than locking it makes the most sense to me.

Comment: I think this course of action is most sensible.

Answer (score 2):

If we are going to lock them (which seems like a reasonably good idea in this case) merging them seems a bit over eager. They are being locked for historical interest they should be locked as they are.